Are you able to publish two different azure git repositories to the same azure data factory instance?
I have a data factory in azure called df-sandbox-dev. I am being told that we need to have multiple repositories deploy to that azure data factory instance. RepoA, RepoB and RepoC. They all have different code and pipeline functions. If we connect RepoA and publish. Then disconnect from RepoA, and connect to RepoB then publish RepoB. Will what is in RepoB override what was deployed from RepoA? Or will it all combine up in the data factory instance?
I am new to Azure Data Factory, and conceptually I can't imagine that this is possible. But thought maybe I was missing something. Any insights would be helpful.
For example: repoA has pipeline1. And RepoB has pipeline2. We connect RepoA and publish. We disconnect RepoA and connect RepoB and publish. What is in the data factory instance? pipeline1 and pipeline2 or just pipeline2?

I don;t think that is supported: You can associate a data factory with an Azure Repos Git organization repository for source control, collaboration, versioning, and so on. A single Azure Repos Git organization can have multiple repositories, but an Azure Repos Git repository can be associated with only one data factory. I https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#author-with-azure-repos-git-integration

Why is the single datafactory spread out over multiple repos anyway?

@PeterBons repo strategy wise, we were going to do every pipeline (or pipeline project) in its own repo vs. having one repo with many folders and spans multiple projects. Someone on the team was thinking we could deploy multiple repositories to the same DF and have them all live in the same ecosystem, which as I do more training it seems like you said, its not supported, especially since the ARM template is the source of truth - we would essentially be deploying multiple arm templates to the same DF across different repos. (disconnecting and reconnecting repos)

In Azure Data Factory (ADF), each instance should be connected to only one Git repository. This ensures that all changes and versions are tracked consistently within a single source of truth that is the ARM template. However, you can create multiple local branches within that repository to facilitate parallel development. This allows different team members to work on separate features or fixes simultaneously. Once the changes in these local branches have been tested and validated, they can be merged into the collaboration branch. After merging, you can publish the changes from the collaboration branch to adf_publish branch and deploy it to the next higher environment.
Different environment like dev , UAT, preprod, prod would have different ADF instance and corresponding repositories.
